# Clone Laravel 4 Project - Permission Problems

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I cloned a project on my local machine and used it as a starting point for another project.  I've been plagued by permission problems ever since.

Whenever I clear the cache, I notice that nothing happens.  I get no error, but the cache doesn't in fact clear.  Trying to manually delete the files is not allowed.  Trying to change permissions on the files is not allowed.

```
$ chmod -R 777 app/storage
chmod: Unable to change file mode on app/storage/cache/14: Operation not permitted
```

The only thing that works is using sudo:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage
$ php artisan cache:clear
```

And this will only work for a single page load.  All future attempts to clear that cache fail silently and again require the above procedure.

How can I fix this issue and get the permissions working properly again?

**SOLUTION:**

I made a change to my local Apache settings following this procedure:
http://paulmason.name/item/change-apache-user-group-in-lion-os-x

A final sudo chmod got me up and running.

Comment: `chown` that directory to make it both readable & writable for the user _you_ use on the command line, and for the user of the _webserver_. A common one is `chown youruser:www-data app/storage && chmod 0770 app/storage`, but it depends on those _2_ users.

Comment: Why is it that starting a project from scratch (clone from Github w/ composer install) does not produce this problem?

Comment: Likely, because you copied over folders _including their ownership_? Hard to tell without `ls -ld` output of the folders in question.